# hashed password is different from database hashed password each time I run a test, even if the password is the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, bcrypt

Im implementing a REST API, Im trying to do a test to update the password, the problem I am having is everytime I try to do it the hash is always different even if the password is the same the hash never matches, everytime I do a new test I get a new hash even if I use the same password, I don't know what to do, can someone help me here?

user.js:

```
  const getUserById = async (userId) => {
    try {
      const user = await app.db('users').where({ id: userId }).first();
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const updatePasswordDashboard = async (data) => {
    try {
        const user = await getUserById(data.id);
        console.log('Stored Password:', user.password);
        console.log('Hashed Password from Request:', getPasswdHash(data.password));
        console.log('Password Request:', data.password);

    if(getPasswdHash(data.password) === user.password){
      if (data.newPassword === data.confirmNewPassword) {
        try {
          const newPassHash = getPasswdHash(data.newPassword);
  
          const updatedUser = await app.db('users')
            .returning(['password', 'first_name'])
            .where({ id: data.id })
            .update({ password: newPassHash });
  
          return updatedUser;
        } catch (error) {
          return error;
        }
      } else {
        throw new ValidationError('Palavras-passes nao coincidem!');
      }
    }
    else{
      throw new ValidationError('Palavra-passe errada!');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
   
  };
```

users.js:

```
  router.put('/updatepassworddashboard/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log('Request received:', req.body);
 
      const result = await app.services.user.updatePasswordDashboard({
        id: req.params.id, password: req.body.password, newPassword: req.body.newPassword, confirmNewPassword: req.body.confirmNewPassword,
      });
      return res.status(200).json({ resultado: result[0], message: 'Palavra-passe alterada com sucesso' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).json({ error: err });
    }
  });
```

users.test.js:

```
  test('Teste 12 - Atualizar palavra passe - dashboard', () => request(app).put(`${MAIN_ROUTE}/updatepassworddashboard/${user.id}`)
  .set('authorization', `bearer ${user.token}`)
  .send({ password: '12345', newPassword: '1234567', confirmNewPassword: '1234567',})
  .then((res) => {
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    expect(res.body.password).not.toBe('');
  }));
```

I checked the hashes and did some console.logs to try to find the issue but I can't find it.

Comment: This is expected. When you hash a password, a random salt is added to it. Each time you hash, the random salt is different, so the hash is different.

Comment: The salt is saved along with the password hash. To validate the password, you extract the salt, use that when hashing, and then compare.

Comment: Sorry, how do you extract the salt? Is there a command for it? I only save the hash, im new on this.